# Cohomology and deformations of moduli of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

I believe that the following is well-known, but I cannot find a reference
in the literature...

Let $X$ be a smooth variety (in our case $X = M^s(r)$ coarse moduli space of **stable** rank $r$ vector bundles with trivial determinant over a curve $C$ , so $X$ is **not compact** !) and
let $L$ be a line bundle over $X$. Then we have the standard exact sequence

$$0 \to O_X \to Diff^1(L) \to T_X \to 0$$

now take the long exact sequence of cohomology

$$ ... \to H^1(O_X) \to H^1(Diff^1(L)) \to H^1(T_X) \to H^2(O_X) \to ...$$

Since $Pic(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ , we obtain $H^1(O_X) = 0$. Do we also have $H^2(O_X) = 0$, so that the
middle arrow is an isomorphism ? 
It is natural to expect that

$$dim (H^1(T_X)) = dim (H^1(C, T_C)) = 3g-3,$$

so that any infinitesimal deformation of the moduli 
comes from a deformation of the curve, but I can find the result only for the coprime case (Narasimhan, Ramanan) and not trivial determinant.

Is this true for trivial determinant as well?

Comment: Certainly there exist smooth varieties such that $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is nonozero.  However, the coarse moduli space of stable vector bundles is smooth and unirational, so it might well be that $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is zero.  When the degree of the (fixed) determinant is prime to the rank, then $X$ is projective, smooth and unirational, hence $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is zero if the characteristic is $0$ (and probably there is an argument valid in all characteristics).

Comment: Yes in fact that's what I knew

Comment: sorry, I meant: Thank you, Jason. Yes in fact that's what I knew. In the case of stable bundles with trivial determinant the variety is still smooth and unirational, but just quasi-projective...

Comment: It is not clear to me why $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$. I do not think that your argument suffices: if $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^2$ with one point removed, $Pic(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, but $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is nonzero (and in fact infinite-dimensional).

Comment: sorry Olivier, I might not have been clear. I am only talking about the case when $X$ is the moduli space.

Comment: @IMeasy Yes: I agree. I am not claiming that your statement that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ is false (I do not know that), but that the argument you give does not suffice to prove it (as far as I understand).

Comment: @OlivierBenoist:  You are certainly correct about the complement of a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$.  A naive estimate suggests that the strictly semistable locus in the moduli space has codimension, approximately, $(r-2)(g-1)$ (something seems wrong when $r$ equals $2$ ...).  If the compact moduli space were smooth, removing a subset of very high codimension would not affect $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: I made an arithmetic mistake in computing the codimension above.  It should be $(r-1)(g-1)-1$.  So if $(r-1)(g-1) - 1 \geq 4$, i.e., $(r-1)(g-1) \geq 5$, we might naively expect the corresponding cohomology with supports in the boundary to vanish in the range necessary to give vanishing of $h^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: I think the (Kodaira-Spencer) map $H^1(T_C)\to H^1(T_X)$ is only known to be injective, see Hitchin's "Flat connections and geometric quantization", section 5. There are isoms $H^1(T_C)\to H^0(Sym^2 T_X)$ though, ibid.

Comment: If $g=r=2$ the moduli space is affine. For general $g$ and $r=2$ there is a relatively explicit description of the moduli space (if $C$ is hyperelliptic) due to Desale and Ramanan from which you can probably check whether the vanishing holds.